# openai migrate error in google-colaboratory notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory, openai-api

I'm new to colab and am running the following in my notebook:

```
**%pip install --upgrade openai

import openai

openai.api_key = "XX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

completion = openai.Completion.create(engine="text-davinci-003", prompt="Where is the least expensive ski resort near Oklahoma City OK?", max_tokens=1000)
print(completion.choices[0]['text'])**
```

When I get to the above completion statement, I get the following message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
APIRemovedInV1                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-12930ca51aa9> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 completion = openai.Completion.create(engine="text-davinci-003", prompt="Where is the least expensive ski resort near Dallas TX?", max_tokens=1000)
      2 print(completion.choices[0]['text'])

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/openai/lib/_old_api.py in __call__(self, *_args, **_kwargs)
     37 
     38     def __call__(self, *_args: Any, **_kwargs: Any) -> Any:
---> 39         raise APIRemovedInV1(symbol=self._symbol)
     40 
     41 

APIRemovedInV1: 

You tried to access openai.Completion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.

You can run `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface. 

Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. `pip install openai==0.28`

A detailed migration guide is available here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742
```

However, when I try to run the below statement, I get an error:

```
openai migrate

  File "<ipython-input-14-424aeda019d3>", line 1
    openai migrate
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there another format or process for migrating my code in colab?

I've tried the following:

```
'openai migrate' just after the 'import openai' directive.

'openai.migrate'

I've tried positioning the openai migrate command at different places in the code.

Searching for colab and 'openai migrate'
```